# Width calculations in jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use this code to toggle a navbar on the right side of my website.
However, is there a way to get the initial widths recalled in my 2nd script?

I cannot get `width: calc(100% - 656px);` to work for me. Does someone have an alternative? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Javascript**

```
 $('.arrowexpand').click(function(){
    $('.navbar_right').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    $('#wrap').animate({width: '84.4%'});
    $('#new_playersin').animate({width: '56.1%'});
 });

 $('.getback').click(function(){
    $('.navbar_right').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    $('#wrap').animate({width: 'X-MARKS-THE-ISSUE'});
    $('#new_playersin').animate({width: '24.9%'});
 });
```

Comment: You could do the calculation yourself: `$('#wrap').animate({width: $('#wrap').width() - 656 })`

Comment: @DJDavid98 If I set the div to a specific px size or % and re-size my browser window, the div does not fit - as it is set to calc because of a div on left and right of my page.

Comment: So you can do this in `$(window).resize` too. Can you create a snippet or fiddle? It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: I figured another way to do it, $("#wrap").css("width", "calc(100% - 656px)");